# x86 asm printf causes segfault when using intel syntax (gcc)

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, printf

I'm just starting to learn x86 assembly, and I am a bit confused as to why this little example doesn't work. All I want to do is to print the content of the eax register as a decimal value. This is my code in AT&T Syntax:

```
.data
intout:
    .string "%d\n"
.text
.globl main

main:

movl $666, %eax
pushl %eax
pushl $intout
call printf

movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

Which I compile and run as follows:

```
gcc -m32 -o hello helloworld.S
./hello
```

This works as excepted (Printing 666 to the console). On a little side note, I would like to point out that I don't understand what exactly *"movl $1, %eax"* and *"int $0x80"* are supposed to accomplish here. I'm also a not sure what *"pushl $intout"* does. Why is my output composed out of two separate stack entries? And what exactly does the .string macro do?

These are only side questions however, since my **real** problem is that I can't find a way to make this run using the much easier to read/write/comprehend Intel syntax.

Here is the code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.data
    intout:
        .string "%d\n"
.text
.globl main

main:

mov eax, 666
push eax
push intout
call printf

mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

Running this same as above, it just prints "Segmentation fault".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In fact it's not recommended to use the `movl $1,%eax; int $0x80`. You should just `call exit` if you are using the C library as you are. Or you could just `ret`, assuming you clean up the stack properly which you don't do. You have 2 entries beause you pass 2 arguments (the format string and the number). As for what `.string` does, I think you can guess that, or, you know, read the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/String.html).

Comment: What is the difference between int 0x80 and call exit?

Comment: The former is a direct system call which leaves no opportunity for the C library to shut down properly. Also it's less portable.

Comment: So the C library basically abstracts this away, based on which system it was compiled?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `push OFFSET intout` otherwise the 32-bit value stored at `intout` will be pushed on the stack, rather than its address.

`intout` is just a label, which is basically a name assigned to an address in your program.  The `.string "%d\n"` directive that follows it defines a sequence of bytes in your program, both allocating memory and initializing that memory. Specifically it allocates 4 bytes in the `.data` section and initializes them with the characters `'%'`, `'d'`, `'\n'`, and `'\0'`. Since the label `intout` is defined just before the `.string` line it has the address of the first byte in the string.

The line `push intout` results in a instruction that reads the 4 bytes starting at the address of referred to by intout and pushes them on to the stack (specifically it subtracts 4 from ESP and then copies them to the 4 bytes now pointed to by ESP.) The line `push $intout` (or `push OFFSET intout`) pushes the 4 bytes that make up the 32-bit address of `intout` on the stack.

This means that the line `push intout` pushes a meaningless value on to the stack. The function `printf` ends up interpreting it as a pointer, an address where the format string is supposed to be stored, but since it doesn't point to valid location in memory your program crashes.

Comment: Does this only apply to the Intel syntax?

Comment: The `$` in at&t syntax did the same.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks. Also how on earth does this even work? Where is intout stored, why does it know that the number to format is on the stack. I'm so confused. Is there a guide anywhere to better understand how this works. My lectures have only covered registers and flow control thus far.